# Sign and Arrow alignment

Tags: formatting, chemfig

I'm trying to get the arrow and the right hand side of both these equations to align horizontally with the 'n's and + sign. I tried rewriting the chemfig molecules, though that only helped align the 'n's with the + sign. If anyone has any suggestions that would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\tabulinesep = ^ 4mm _ 4mm % border gap
\begin{tabu} to 13cm {|X[cm]|}
    \hline
    \schemestart
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \scalebox{1.25}{\textit{n}}
    \hspace{0.5mm}
    \scalebox{0.75}{\chemfig{(-[:150,0.75]H|O)-[:30](-[:-30,0.75]O|H)}}
    \+
    \scalebox{1.25}{\textit{n}}
    \hspace{0.5mm}
    \scalebox{0.75}{\chemfig{(-[:150,0.75]H|O)(=[:-90,0.75]O)-[:30](=[:90,0.75]O)(-[:-30,0.75]O|H)}}
    \arrow[,,thick]
    \scalebox{0.7}{\chemfig{-[@{left,.65}:30,0.75]O-[:-30]-[:30]O-[:-30](=[:-90,0.75]O)-[:30](=[:90,0.75]O)-[@{right,0.45}:-30,0.75]}
    \polymerdelim[height = 20pt, depth = 20pt, indice = \!\!n]{left}{right}}
    \schemestop
    \\
    \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\tabulinesep = ^ 4mm _ 4mm % border gap
\begin{tabu} to 13cm {|X[cm]|}
    \hline
    \schemestart
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \scalebox{1.25}{\textit{n}}
    \hspace{0.5mm}
    \scalebox{0.75}{\chemfig{(-[:150,0.75]H_2|N)-[:30](-[:-30,0.75]N|H_2)}}
    \+
    \scalebox{1.25}{\textit{n}}
    \hspace{0.5mm}
    \scalebox{0.75}{\chemfig{(-[:150,0.75]Cl)(=[:-90,0.75]O)-[:30](=[:90,0.75]O)(-[:-30,0.75]Cl)}}
    \arrow[,,thick]
    \scalebox{0.7}{\chemfig{-[@{left,.65}:30,0.75]N(-[:90,0.3,,,draw=none]H)-[:-30]-[:30]N(-[:90,0.3,,,draw=none]H)-[:-30](=[:-90,0.75]O)-[:30](=[:90,0.75]O)-[@{right,0.45}:-30,0.75]}
    \polymerdelim[height = 20pt, depth = 20pt, indice = \!\!n]{left}{right}}
    \schemestop
    \\
    \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

use `\chemabove` and `\chembelow` to put something above or below atoms in the molecule.

I modified the last reaction molecule.

Try this:

```
% SECOND EQUATION
\begin{center}
    \tabulinesep = ^ 4mm _ 4mm % border gap
    \begin{tabu} to 15cm {|X[cm]|}
        \hline
        \schemestart
        \arrow{0}[,0]
        \scalebox{1.25}{\textit{n}}
        \hspace{0.5mm}
        \scalebox{0.75}{\chemfig{(-[:150,0.75]H_2|N)-[:30](-[:-30,0.75]N|H_2)}}
        \+
        \scalebox{1.25}{\textit{n}}
        \hspace{0.5mm}
        \scalebox{0.75}{\chemfig{(-[:150,0.75]Cl)(=[:-90,0.75]O)-[:30](=[:90,0.75]O)(-[:-30,0.75]@{y}Cl)}}
        \arrow(@{y}--[yshift=-6pt]){->[][][-2pt]}[,,thick]
        \scalebox{0.7}{\chemfig{\chemabove{N}{H}(-[@{left}:210])-[:330]-[:30]\chemabove{N}{H}-[:330](=[6]O)-[:30](=[2]O)-[@{right}:330]}
            \polymerdelim[height = 20pt, depth = 20pt, indice = \!\!n]{left}{right}}
        \schemestop
        \\
        \hline
    \end{tabu}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: Also a follow up question, do you know how I would move the diamine molecule on the left by a few pt down?

Comment: TRICK: place the beginning of the diamine molecule in the middle of the first bond       \scalebox{0.75}{\chemfig{(-[:150,0.37]H_2|N)-[:330,.37]-[:30](-[:-30,0.75]N|H_2)}}